# I can't solve an equation with a parameter.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have equation $$\log^2_{3}(7x^2+1)+(3a^2-a+3)\cdot\log_3(7x^2 +1)+4a^2-a^4=0$$
We need to find all values ​​of the parameter$ \ a $ for which there is at least one solution.
My solution
$\ 7x^2+1 \gt 1 \Rightarrow \log_3 (7x^2+1) \ge 0 $ We can replace $\log_3(7x^2+1)  $ on $\ t $
Then the original equation becomes $\ t^2+(3a^2-a+3)*t + 4a^2 - a^4=0 $ According to Vieta's theorem $\ x_1\cdot x_2=c $
Then $\ t_1\cdot t_2=4a^2 - a^4 $
and $$\ 4a^2 - a^4 \ge 0  \Rightarrow a\subset (-\infty:-4] \cup [1, 5:-\infty) $$  But answer is $\ a\subset(-4:1,5) $
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does $t^2+(3a^2−a+3)t+4a^2−a^4$ $a\subset (-\infty:-4] \cup [1, 5:-\infty)$? 
Also, for $$t^2+(3a^2−a+3)t+4a^2−a^4$$ to have at least one solution, it must hold that $$(3a^2-a+3)^2-4(4a^2-a^4)\ge0$$ but that is true $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Note that $ 4a^2 - a^4 \geq 0 \Rightarrow  -2 \leq a \leq 2 $. EG It's obvious that $ - \infty$ can't be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints towards a solution. Fill in the gaps as needed.

- We want there to be a non-negative solution $ t \geq 0$.
- The solution needs to be real, which means that the discrimant needs to be ...  As Mathematician  By Mistake points out, the roots are always real.
- The sum of roots is $ - (3a^2 - a+3)$, which is always negative.
- We cannot have two negative roots, which means that their product has to be ...

Note: Your given answer is incorrect. EG show that for $ a = -1$, the roots  are negative.